# Regex decimal values between 0 and 1 up to 4 decimal places

Tags: regex

I am writing a C# web application and verify data in a textbox using this regular expression that only accepts positive decimal values between 0 and 1:

```
^(0(\.\d+)?|1(\.0+)?)$
```

I would to adapt like the regex to restrict entries to 4 decimal places of precision.

**Allowed**

```
0
0.1
0.12
0.123
0.1234
1
```

**Not allowed**

```
-0.1
-1
1.1
2
```

I have found the following regex that only allows up to 4 decimal places, but I am unsure on how to combine the two.

```
^(?!0\d|$)\d*(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set replace the `+` quantifier with the limiting `{1,4}`:

```
^(0(\.[0-9]{1,4})?|1(\.0{1,4})?)$
           ^^^^^        ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vFMCcI/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - Outer group start

  - `0` - a zero
  - `(\.[0-9]{1,4})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` followed with 1 to 4 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `1` - a `1`
  - `(\.0{1,4})?)` - an optional sequence of `.` followed with 1 to 4 zeros
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Note you may use a version with non-capturing groups, too: `^(?:0(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?|1(?:\.0{1,4})?)$` (however, in this case, there is little difference, choose the one that appeals to you)

Answer (score 0):

This can be used as the validation function that allows four digit decimal place in terms of regular expession (RegExp).

```js
function fourdecimalplace(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    var re = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;
    var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)/g;

    if (re.test(val)) {
        //do something here

    } else {
        val = re1.exec(val);
        if (val) {
            this.value = val[0];
        } else {
            this.value = "";
        }
    }
```